# Problem with input language

Tags: input-language

I just tried to use Ubuntu 18.10. I have two input source languages, English and Greek. When i change to Greek i still write English. I did not had this issue with the other versions. Is it a bug?

Comment: Please reboot and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I also tried to reboot but the problem still exists

Comment: How do you change layout? Do you see the `gr` symbol in the top bar? What's the output of this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'gr')]

Comment: the above is what i get from the command. I also have checked thn gr symbol for the input language

Comment: That output looks good. Sorry, then I have no more ideas. I can't reproduce the problem on my 18.04.

Comment: The problem is only at ubuntu 18.10. The previews versions everything worked just fine. I think this is a program bug and i dont know were i can send this report to fix it